# SQL - Join table where t1.value matches t2.column name?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables containing survey settings and survey data.

[image]

The idea is to join the two tables by the **survey question** which is defined in the **settings** as a value, with the matching **survey question** column of the **data** table, extracting the survey score of that question.

How can I join 2 tables based on a value + column combination, and then extract the survey scores for a specific survey?

I am currently only getting data from the survey data table, but I am lacking the `category` column from the settings which makes it hard to categorize the output on the website since I dont want to show all data at once. My PHP below for reference:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `survey_data` WHERE `Survey ID` = '".$id."'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);         // check if record exists based on ID number

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {         // if record is found, proceed accordingly

        if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) {
            die('There was an error getting survey details for record ' . $id . ' [' . $db->error . ']'); }

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        foreach($row as $column => $value) {
            if ( $value != '' ) {
                echo "
                          <tr>
                            <td>$column</td>
                            <td>$value</td>
                          </tr>";
            }
        }
```

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Your table design has some problems, because there is no clear primary-foreign key relationship between the two tables.

Comment: The relationship would be the question value from the settings table and the column name containing the question answer of the survey data table. The problem is that the relationship is not traditional value to value, but rather value to column.

Comment: Value to column name is not really how a database should be setup.

Comment: No, no, no. Fix your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: @Strawberry sadly not an option as the survey_data content comes from a csv import where the column header names come from system generated headers, hence the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Query:

```
SELECT * FROM survey_data sd inner join setting_table st on sd.Survey ID = st.setting ID WHERE `Survey ID` = '".$id."'
```

It will return all columns from both tables but only matched.And retrive the data like this.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "survey question: " . $row["question"]."<br>";
    }
```

Now you can also fetch the category of the respective row

Comment: Thanks for that, but the query returns no results. Table names and colums are correct, even if I remove the `Survey ID = XXX` part, it still has no result even though it should show all rows.

Comment: On a note, your query matches the `Survey_ID` to the `Setting_ID` which are not the same, instead the st.question and sd.column_name are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The query is rather messy, but you can take a brute-force approach:

```
select t2.survey_id, t1.category, t1.question,
       (case when t1.question = 'Check-in Experience' then t2.`Check-in Experience`
             when t1.question = 'Check-out Experience' then t2.`Check-out Experience`
             when t1.question = 'Breakfast Experience' then `Breakfast Experience`
        end) as value
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2
where t2.survey_id = ?
having value is not null;
```